# How to update table conditionally using ibatis?

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I want to update a table in Postgres using ibatis dbmapper.xml.

Condition is it should update only those columns for which the map contains values. For other columns the value should not be touched.

Say I have a Company Table with following columns {company_id, name, headQrtr, ceo}

If i want to update any particular row in Company table using company_id, I will be having following code snippet(dbmapper.xml)

```
<update id="update_company_details" parameterType="map">
    update Company set (name,headQrtr,ceo) values(${name_value},${headQrtr_value},${ceo_value}) where company_id=${company_id_value}
</update>
```

This works fine if I update all the three columns.

But there will be scenarios where I just want to update the ceo column, in that case my input map will be having only one key(i.e ceo_value) and rest of the keys are not available.
In that case the other columns are getting updated with blank values. So how can I restrict that?

I was thinking of using 'if' tag, but not sure how to use it for setting values for different columns?

Comment: Got the solution....https://stackoverflow.com/a/22854769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
<update id="update_company_details" parameterType="map">
        UPDATE Company
        <set>
            <if test="name_value!= null">
                name = #{name_value},
            </if>
            <if test="headQrtr_value!= null">
                headQrtr= #{headQrtr_value},
            </if>
            <if test="ceo_value!= null">
                ceo= #{ceo_value},
            </if>
        </set>
        WHERE company_id= #{company_id_value}
    </update>
```